# How to print spaces in Python?

Tags: python

In C++, `\n` is used, but what do I use in Python?

I don't want to have to use:
`print ("   ")`.
This doesn't seem very elegant.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean spaces or line breaks?

Comment: `\n` is a newline in C++.  Not a space

Answer (score 21):

Here's a short answer

```
x=' '
```

This will print one white space

```
print(x)
```

This will print 10 white spaces

```
print(10*x)
```

Print 10 whites spaces between `Hello` and `World`

```
print(f"Hello{x*10}World")
```

Comment: The Parentheses are not needed.
Also, I personally feel the + notation is messy, hard to read, and should be avoided.
I prefer to use string format replacement ( %s ) instead. I have typed out a long explanation / answer below.

Comment: To be clear, parentheses may not be needed in Python 2, but they are most definitely needed in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to separate certain elements with spaces you could do something like

```
print "hello", "there"
```

Notice the comma between "hello" and "there".

If you want to print a new line (i.e. `\n`) you could just use `print` without any arguments.

Comment: just using print does not seem to output newline? or cannot be used as an empty line?

Comment: `print` alone should output a new line, try running this: `print "hello" ; print ; print "world"`, and the compare it with what would happen if you remove the middle `print`.

Comment: arg, this darn comment textarea I am typing in doesn't really allow for line breaks, which made the first comment I typed here, unhelpful.  I am editing it, just please refer to the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 6):

A lone `print` will output a newline.

```
print
```

In 3.x `print` is a function, therefore:

```
print()
```

Answer (score 4):

`print("hello" + ' '*50 + "world")`

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following will work:

```
print 'Hello\nWorld'

print 'Hello'
print 'World'
```

Additionally, if you want to print a blank line (not make a new line), `print` or `print()` will work.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, for newlines, the simplest thing to do is have separate print statements, like this:

```
print("Hello")
print("World.")
#the parentheses allow it to work in Python 2, or 3.
```

To have a line break, and still only one print statement, simply use the "\n" within, as follows:

```
print("Hello\nWorld.")
```

Below, I explain spaces, instead of line breaks...

I see allot of people here using the + notation, which personally, I find ugly. 
Example of what I find ugly:

```
x=' ';
print("Hello"+10*x+"world");
```

The example above is currently, as I type this the top up-voted answer.  The programmer is obviously coming into Python from PHP as the ";" syntax at the end of every line, well simple isn't needed.  The only reason it doesn't through an error in Python is because semicolons CAN be used in Python, really should only be used when you are trying to place two lines on one, for aesthetic reasons.  You shouldn't place these at the end of every line in Python, as it only increases file-size.

Personally, I prefer to use %s notation. In Python 2.7, which I prefer, you don't need the parentheses, "(" and ")".  However, you should include them anyways, so your script won't through errors, in Python 3.x, and will run in either.

Let's say you wanted your space to be 8 spaces, 
So what I would do would be the following in Python > 3.x

```
print("Hello", "World.",  sep=' '*8, end="\n")
# you don't need to specify end, if you don't want to, but I wanted you to know it was also an option
#if you wanted to have an 8 space prefix, and did not wish to use tabs for some reason, you could do the following.
print("%sHello World." % (' '*8))
```

The above method will work in Python 2.x as well, but you cannot add the "sep" and "end" arguments, those have to be done manually in Python < 3.

**Therefore**, to have an 8 space prefix, with a 4 space separator, the syntax which would work in Python 2, or 3 would be:

```
print("%sHello%sWorld." % (' '*8, ' '*4))
```

I hope this helps.

P.S.  You also could do the following.

```
>>> prefix=' '*8
>>> sep=' '*2
>>> print("%sHello%sWorld." % (prefix, sep))
    Hello  World.
```

Answer (score 2):

rjust() and ljust()

```
test_string = "HelloWorld"

test_string.rjust(20)
'          HelloWorld'

test_string.ljust(20)
'HelloWorld          '
```

Answer (score 2):

Space char is hexadecimal 0x20, decimal 32 and octal \040.

```py
>>> SPACE = 0x20
>>> a = chr(SPACE)
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(f"'{a}'")
' '
```

Comment: Space char is hexadecimal 0x20, decimal 32 and octal \040.what is the encoding and why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try`print`

Example:

```
print "Hello World!"
print
print "Hi!"
```

Hope this works!:)

Answer (score 0):

this is how to print whitespaces in python.

```
import string  
string.whitespace  
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '   
i.e .   
print "hello world"   
print "Hello%sworld"%' '   
print "hello", "world"   
print "Hello "+"world
```

Answer (score 0):

simply assign a variable to `()` or `" "`, then when needed type

```
print(x, x, x, Hello World, x)
```

or something like that.

Hope this is a little less complicated:)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `pprint()` in `pprint` module works wonder, especially for `dict` variables.

Answer (score 0):

To print any amount of lines between printed text use:

`print("Hello" + '\n' *`*insert number of whitespace lines*`+ "World!")`

'\n' can be used to make whitespace, multiplied, it will make multiple whitespace lines.

Answer (score 0):

In Python2 there's this.

```py
def Space(j):
    i = 0
    while i<=j:
        print " ",
        i+=1
```

And to use it, the syntax would be:

```
Space(4);print("Hello world")
```

I haven't converted it to Python3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of users gave you answers, but you haven't marked any as an answer.

You add an empty line with `print()`.
You can force a new line inside your string with `'\n'` like in `print('This is one line\nAnd this is another')`, therefore you can print 10 empty lines with `print('\n'*10)`

You can add 50 spaces inside a sting by replicating a one-space string 50 times, you can do that with multiplication `'Before' + ' '*50 + 'after 50 spaces!'`

You can pad strings to the left or right, with spaces or a specific character, for that you can use `.ljust()` or `.rjust()` for example, you can have 'Hi' and 'Carmen' on new lines, padded with spaces to the left and justified to the right with `'Hi'.rjust(10) + '\n' + 'Carmen'.rjust(10)`

I believe these should answer your question.