# How do I print an integer with a set number of spaces before it?

Tags: python, printing, integer

C has `printf("%Xd", Y);`, which just prints the integer X and makes it take Y spaces on the console window.

For example:

```
printf("%3d", 10);
console: " 10"`

printf("%5d", 5);
console: "    5"
```

How do I use this in python 3?

Comment: print('%10d'%20)

Comment: You can see the solution in following url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450704/how-to-print-spaces-in-python

Answer (score 5):

This `print("{0:10d}".format(5))` will print 5 after 9 blanks.
For more reference on formatting in python refer [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php).

Answer (score 5):

In general case, we could use string [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html):

```
>>> '{:<30}'.format('left aligned')
'left aligned                  '
>>> '{:>30}'.format('right aligned')
'                 right aligned'
>>> '{:^30}'.format('centered')
'           centered           '
>>> '{:*^30}'.format('centered')  # use '*' as a fill char
'***********centered***********'
```

We could also do that with f strings for python >3.6

```
>>> f"{'left aligned':<30}"
'left aligned                  '
>>> f"{'right aligned':>30}"
'                 right aligned'
>>> f"{'centered':^30}"
'           centered           '
>>> f"{'centered':*^30}"  # use '*' as a fill char
'***********centered***********'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
>>> print(10*' ',10)
           10
>>> print(5*' ',5)
      5
>>> x=5
>>> print(x*' ',x)
      5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using [ljust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) or [rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust):

These python methods take a string and `pad` it either on the left or right to make it a set number of `chars` for printing to the console as you want.

To give an example with `.rjust`:

```
num = 1234
chars = 9
print(str(num).rjust(chars))
```

this will output:

```
"     1234"
```

or using `.ljust` would give you:

```
"1234     "
```

One thing to note is that `.ljust` and `.rjust` are significantly different to printing a set number of spaces `' '` before or after the `int` as they allow you to specify the **total** length of the string rather than the whitespace before it. This is a key thing to consider for example when printing a table as with these methods, the *columns* can be made to be set *widths* making it neat. Whereas simply adding *spaces* beforehand will result in varying *widths* as the number of `digits` of the `integers` will change causing the **total** string length to change making the widths vary.

Of course, if you wanted to, you could still specify the **total** string length and then calculate how many spaces need placing before or after the `int`.

So `.rjust` may be something like:

```
num = 1234
chars = 9
print(' ' * (chars - len(str(num))) + str(num))
```

noticing that here, I have *concatenated* the `num` as a string onto the whitespace with `+` rather than using a comma in the print statement as the comma will place an added space between the two.

and `.ljust`  would be the same but the `num` printed first:

```
print(str(num) + ' ' * (chars - len(str(num))))
```

however, all this work is unnecessary and looks very messy considering you can just use the original two built-in python methods :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
x = " "
y = 10
print((x*5), y)
```

And your output will be

```
     10
```

You assign x to a string with a space, then when printing, you simply multiply the string with space by the number of spaces you want before y.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the C-like printf in python3:

Your C printf:

```
printf("%3d", 10);
console: " 10"`

printf("%5d", 5);
console: "    5"
```

In Python3 is:

```
print("%3d" % (10));
console: " 10"`

print("%5d" %  (5));
console: "    5"
```

So to use the C-like printf in Python3, put a "%" instead of a ",".
After that, you just need to use a tuple for the arguments.

A more general case (I get a debug trace from one of my programs):

```
print("Router: %-5s, subnetToDest: %-20s with hop: %-20s" % (r, s[0], s[1]))
Router: r0   , subnetToDest: 100.30.0.0/16        with hop: Local
```

PD, the - in the last example means right alignment.